# How to declare method (function) with multiples input parameters and out parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, methods

I am trying to declare a method that has multiple input and output parameters.
I have no problems with multiple input parameters declaration like this:

```
     - (float)tCorrection:(float)t2 tCableBase:(float)t1 CableMaterial: (NSString*)CopperOrAl;
```

In this case we have 3 input parameters (different types) and one float return type.

My problem is how to declare a function that has more that 1 return parameters. I tried different syntax's and no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the values you need to return ?

Comment: Why don't you use `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableArray` ?

Comment: I agree with lxt, what you need is a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way of returning multiple values is:

- wrap it up and return a struct
- wrap it up and return a class
- return a dictionary/array

Using a pass-by-reference approach should generally not be used and is used mostly
for `NSError**`.

Answer (score 1):

First, your method name is really sub-optimal. Instead of:

```
     - (float)tCorrection:(float)t2 tCableBase:(float)t1 CableMaterial: (NSString*)CopperOrAl;
```

I would suggest something like:

```
 - (float)applyCorrection:(float)correction toCableBase:(float)cableBase withCableMaterial:(CableMaterial)material;
```

Where you define `CableMaterial` to be an enumerated type of materials.

Next, to answer your question, you *could* use return-by-reference as **duDE** suggests.

But, don't.   Smells like bad design.

Instead, it really sounds like you need a class whose instances can be configured with various parameters and then queried to get the calculated results.   This will produce a much cleaner application design.

I would imagine something like a `Cable` class that has properties like `material`, `base`, `correction`, etc... and then various `readonly` properties that calculate the various needed values.

Comment: Thanks bbum for your comment. It shows me another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Generally There is no any Syntax of Method That Return Multiple Values But If your Have Multiple Values and your want to return it then create `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionary` That useful for return multiple values.

Such Like,

```
- (NSMutableArray *)tCorrection:(float)t2 tCableBase:(float)t1 CableMaterial: (NSString*)CopperOrAl;
{
     NSMutableArray *temArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [temArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", t2]];
     [temArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", t1]];
     [temArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CopperOrAl]];

   return temArray;
}
```

And For Got Value From Return Array

```
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [self tCorrection:2.5 tCableBase:23.5 CableMaterial:@"MyString"];

NSLog(@"%@", returnArray);
```

Comment: I would only do it this way if the number or type of return parameters are unknown at compile time. You'd miss out on compile-time type checking and Objective-C's explicit style and syntax. See duDE's answer for the preferred method.

Comment: Indeed, this approach is rather error prone and you lose type safety, named parameters, clarity and more.